# spring 3.1 maven dependencies and pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I am new to spring .In my office I am first one to use `spring framework`.So there is no guidance for me.So kindly excuse if it is a simple question. so please don't hesitate to edit my question.

Right now I created the simple `employee management MVC application` to do `register`,`delete` and `login employee detatils` with `spring 3.0` . Now willing to move `spring 3.1`

Today I heared about some wordings in spring like`Maven`,`pom.xml`.

In my application I never used the `maven dependencies` and `pom.xml` .I don't know where to use it and when it is needed.

I googled a lot and never find the reliable answer about those things.

Can any one tell me what is `maven` in spring ? when it is used and where to use it ?
Also what about the `pom.xml`.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Maven and Spring are two separate entities. Google them separately and you will find all your answers. Or go their official websites and read the documentation.

Comment: Maven is not something inside Spring.  Maven is a build technology that can build Java projects, and by virtue of various plugins can run unit tests, static code analysis and lots of other things when building your java code.   Spring on the other hand is a framework that your java code may choose to use.  You can use Spring regardless of if you use maven, and vice versa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven dependency for whole org.springframework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398421/maven-dependency-for-whole-org-springframework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) has nothing to do with Spring. It is a project build tool that provides a lot of functionalities such as dependency management, compiling, packaging, unit testing and much more. You could see it as kind of an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)/[makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) on steroids.

The `pom.xml`, or [Project Object Model](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file is the descriptor for *mavenized* projects (that is, projects meant to be built with Maven). In this `pom.xml` file is where you would specify, among many other things, dependencies to Spring, without the need of adding anything to the `CLASSPATH`.

For instance, with Maven properly installed, you could just define this dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And just compile your Spring project with `mvn compile` without adding anything to the classpath. Maven would download every needed dependencies' jars from online repositories. The [getting started](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) guide on Maven's site can be a good resource to start with.

Answer (score 3):

In short:-

**Maven** is a tool that can be used for building and managing any Java-based project.

**pom.xml** is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project.

For complete details, refer the docs. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) , [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)