# Unable to find dependency org.springframework.spring-library on maven central

Tags: spring, maven

Referring to site : 
http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/library/version/detail;jsessionid=DAA99420F19DE8A30A9A869C347ADB8E.jvm1?name=org.springframework.spring&version=3.2.2.RELEASE

the maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.spring-library</artifactId>
    <type>libd</type>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

does not seem to be available :

[image]
Here is the request :

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.springframework.spring-library%22

Should'nt this repository be available on Maven ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven dependency for whole org.springframework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398421/maven-dependency-for-whole-org-springframework)

Comment: @Joe: The solutions may be the same, but the problems are different. So they are not duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add Spring specific repositories in your pom.xml

```
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
    <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
    <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
    <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```

And as mardavi said the maven co-ordinates for Spring also looks wrong.

This [link](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/) might help

Answer (score 0):

I guess

> org.springframework.spring-library

is a placeholder for a generic artifactId. In my knowledge there is no `spring-library` artifact, but several one. If instead of `spring-library` you write `spring-core`, `spring-web` etc then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same issue and solved it. I think it's a bundle of all the spring libraries for a specific version. Why it's not found I cannot say. By replacing it with the individual dependencies I was able to get my code base to work.

Dependencies found here: http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

```
<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<!--
    Core utilities used by other modules.
    Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
    Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- 
    Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
    Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) 
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
    Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans) 
    This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
    Define this if you need any of these integrations
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
    Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
    (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
    Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
    Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
    Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
    This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```