# Spring Annotations Error on Spring Maven Application

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, m2eclipse

On building an application by taking reference from [here](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/03/spring-hibernate-many-to-one.html),

Pom.xml is successfuly saved and all jars are showing on eclipse(Dependency Management).

But Annotations(@Controller,@Service,@Resource) are not recognized in the service and controller classes.

Domain class Annotations(@Entity,etc) are completely recognized and saved.

This problem had not arrived earlier when I first configured maven and eclipse.

After a gap of one week, I am facing this problem.

(After @guido suggestion)

I had add this artificat

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Still, @Service is not recognized by eclipse.

Since, @Resource comes form `javax.annotation.Resource`, I don't understand why its not coming in eclipse.

Kindly Advice.

Comment: do you mean eclipse marks your annotation occurrences with an error? or that spring scanner doesn't find your components at startup?

Comment: yes. eclipse marks your annotation occurrences with an error

Comment: check if *spring-context* dependency is included in you pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do for my spring mvc simple webapp: is to include the following:

This code is pretty basic, if you don't want the Jackson mapper is ok, but is useful if you want to use some @ResponseBody

```
<properties>
  <spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>  
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web / Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

very informative link about spring-mvc dependences:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237537/which-maven-dependencies-to-include-for-spring-3-0)