# Maven ERROR :: package org.springframework.aop.support does not exist

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

when I run maven clean install on my project

it is giving the following error in all the classes

package org.springframework.aop.support does not exist

But I have all the dependencies in my POM file required for spring.

Please help me in finding the reason.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this question: [Which maven dependencies to include for spring 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237537/which-maven-dependencies-to-include-for-spring-3-0)

I know you said you had all the dependencies, but it is hard to determine if there is anything wrong with your POM file without it being displayed.  Make sure your spring-aop dependency is listed as below:

```
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>     
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>     
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Basically, as of Spring version 3.0, there is no one dependency that includes everything.  You need to mix and match based on what you are using, and what you need.  The following website gives a good listing of when you need each of the dependencies: http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

For instance, it mentions that spring-beans depends on spring-core, and spring-context depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, and spring-beans, etc.