# Can't import org.springframework.jdbc.core with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc

I dont know why the follow imports are not getting found in my project:
Code:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlInOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;
```

I have the folllowing in my pom.xml file

Code:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But I have found that if I add the following it works but I dont see why I need to:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is version 3.2.1 out yet ? Yes apparently http://www.springsource.org/node/3791

Comment: You need to include the specific modules you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/2237805/106261

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to work with Spring Jdbc packages you have to import the correct library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

`SqlInOutParameter`, `SqlParameter` and `StoredProcedure` require the [spring-jdbc](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.2.1.RELEASE) artifact.

It does not appear in the [dependent artifacts for `spring-context`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.2.1.RELEASE). The artifact for `spring-orm` *does* contain this dependency however. See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.2.1.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs when you run your Java code using the `CodeRunner` extension in VSCode. This happens because it can only deal with Java files and does not depend on any other third-party dependencies ([reference](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2998)).

The simple solution would be disabling `CodeRunner` and installing something like `Extension Pack for Java` and then the code will compile without errors.