# how to load org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper library

Tags: java

I am trying to execute an open source apache project

i am stopped at an error

Error:(34, 37) java: package org.springframework.jdbc.core does not exist

I tried to load this library but could not find it anywhere

I checked this link

[Can't import org.springframework.jdbc.core with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029292/cant-import-org-springframework-jdbc-core-with-maven)

they talk about another libarary spring-jdbc !!

where can i find the needed library

I have been working on this for 5 days and no luck

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
    <artifactId>ctakes</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Apache cTAKES</name>
    <url>http://ctakes.apache.org</url>
    <inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>
    <scm>
        <!-- In child modules, Maven will append ${artifactId} to the following 
            URLs -->
        <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/tags/ctakes-4.0.0-rc3</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/tags/ctakes-4.0.0-rc3</developerConnection>
        <url>https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/tags/ctakes-4.0.0-rc3</url>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>jira</system>
        <url>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ctakes</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>jenkins</system>
        <url>https://builds.apache.org/job/ctakes-trunk/</url>
    </ciManagement>
    <mailingLists>
        <mailingList>
            <name>Apache cTAKES Users</name>
            <subscribe>user-subscribe@ctakes.apache.org</subscribe>
            <unsubscribe>user-unsubscribe@ctakes.apache.org</unsubscribe>
            <post>user@ctakes.apache.org</post>
            <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ctakes-user/</archive>
        </mailingList>

        <mailingList>
            <name>Apache cTAKES Developers</name>
            <subscribe>dev-subscribe@ctakes.apache.org</subscribe>
            <unsubscribe>dev-unsubscribe@ctakes.apache.org</unsubscribe>
            <post>dev@ctakes.apache.org</post>
            <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ctakes-dev/</archive>
        </mailingList>

        <mailingList>
            <name>Apache cTAKES Commits</name>
            <subscribe>commits-subscribe@ctakes.apache.org</subscribe>
            <unsubscribe>commits-unsubscribe@ctakes.apache.org</unsubscribe>
            <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ctakes-commits/</archive>
        </mailingList>

        <mailingList>
            <name>Apache cTAKES Notifications</name>
            <subscribe>notifications-subscribe@ctakes.apache.org</subscribe>
            <unsubscribe>notifications-unsubscribe@ctakes.apache.org</unsubscribe>
            <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ctakes-notifications/</archive>
        </mailingList>
    </mailingLists>
    <properties>
        <ctakes.version>4.0.0</ctakes.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>ctakes-gui</module>
        <module>ctakes-gui-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-utils</module>
        <module>ctakes-core</module>
        <module>ctakes-type-system</module>
        <module>ctakes-pos-tagger</module>
        <module>ctakes-chunker</module>
        <module>ctakes-preprocessor</module>
        <module>ctakes-dictionary-lookup</module>
        <module>ctakes-context-tokenizer</module>
        <module>ctakes-lvg</module>
        <module>ctakes-ne-contexts</module>
        <module>ctakes-constituency-parser</module>
        <module>ctakes-coreference</module>
        <module>ctakes-drug-ner</module>
        <module>ctakes-side-effect</module>
        <module>ctakes-smoking-status</module>
        <module>ctakes-dependency-parser</module>
        <module>ctakes-relation-extractor</module>
        <module>ctakes-assertion</module>
        <module>ctakes-assertion-zoner</module>
        <module>ctakes-temporal</module>
        <module>ctakes-clinical-pipeline</module>
        <module>ctakes-clinical-pipeline-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-distribution</module>
        <module>ctakes-regression-test</module>
        <module>ctakes-assertion-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-chunker-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-constituency-parser-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-core-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-coreference-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-dependency-parser-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-lvg-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-pos-tagger-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-relation-extractor-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-side-effect-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-smoking-status-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-temporal-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-assertion-zoner-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-drug-ner-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-ne-contexts-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-template-filler</module>
        <module>ctakes-examples</module>
        <module>ctakes-examples-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-ytex-res</module>
        <module>ctakes-ytex</module>
        <module>ctakes-ytex-uima</module>
        <module>ctakes-ytex-web</module>
        <module>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast</module>
        <module>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast-res</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- cTAKES third party dependency versions -->
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>jama</groupId> <artifactId>jama</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version> </dependency> -->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>



            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- There is an xml=apis 2.0 in maven central, but it is pom only, therefore broken.  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--  TODO : Remove jdom and refactor code to jdom2  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jdom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
                <artifactId>opennlp-maxent</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--<dependency>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>uimaj-examples</artifactId>-->
                <!--<version>2.9.0</version>-->
            <!--</dependency>-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>tw.edu.ntu.csie</groupId>
                <artifactId>libsvm</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- import a consistent set of versions for all ClearTK modules -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.cleartk</groupId>
                <artifactId>cleartk</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>args4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.lexicalscope.jewelcli</groupId>
                <artifactId>jewelcli</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>10.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.carrotsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>hppc</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>edu.mit.findstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>structmulti</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>edu.mit.findstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>findstructapi</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.armbrust-file-utils</groupId>
                <artifactId>sqlwrapper</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.openai</groupId>
                <artifactId>openaifsm</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>gov.nih.nlm.nls.lvg</groupId>
                <artifactId>lvgdist</artifactId>
                <version>2016.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.clearnlp</groupId>
                <artifactId>clearnlp</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- cTAKES module versions -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-gui</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-gui-res</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-examples</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-examples-res</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-type-system</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-utils</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-core</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-core-res</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-res</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast-res</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>ctakes-preprocessor</artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion-res
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion-zoner
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion-zoner-res
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-constituency-parser
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-constituency-parser-res
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-relation-extractor
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-relation-extractor-res
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-temporal
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-temporal-res
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-ytex-res
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-ytex
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-ytex-uima
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-ytex-web
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    ctakes-distribution
                </artifactId>
                <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <!-- It's good practice to explicitly declare versions for all plugins -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <header>ctakes-distribution/src/main/config/license_header.txt</header>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- We're disabling .txt files for now because some Annotators may 
                                not be able to handle standard comments in text files. This may break name 
                                values pairs such as stopWords.txt -->
                            <exclude>**.txt</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <useDefaultMapping>false</useDefaultMapping>
                        <quiet>false</quiet>
                        <failIfMissing>false</failIfMissing>
                        <mapping>
                            <java>JAVADOC_STYLE</java>
                            <groovy>JAVADOC_STYLE</groovy>
                            <js>JAVADOC_STYLE</js>
                            <css>JAVADOC_STYLE</css>
                            <xml>XML_STYLE</xml>
                            <dtd>XML_STYLE</dtd>
                            <xsd>XML_STYLE</xsd>
                            <html>XML_STYLE</html>
                            <htm>XML_STYLE</htm>
                            <xsl>XML_STYLE</xsl>
                            <fml>XML_STYLE</fml>
                            <apt>DOUBLETILDE_STYLE</apt>
                            <properties>SCRIPT_STYLE</properties>
                            <sh>SCRIPT_STYLE</sh>
                            <!-- <txt>TEXT</txt> -->
                            <bat>BATCH</bat>
                            <cmd>BATCH</cmd>
                            <sql>DOUBLEDASHES_STYLE</sql>
                            <jsp>DYNASCRIPT_STYLE</jsp>
                            <ftl>FTL</ftl>
                            <xhtml>XML_STYLE</xhtml>
                            <vm>SHARPSTAR_STYLE</vm>
                            <jspx>XML_STYLE</jspx>
                        </mapping>
                        <properties>
                            <owner>Apache Software Foundation</owner>
                            <year>${project.inceptionYear}</year>
                            <email>dev@ctakes.apache.org</email>
                        </properties>
                        <strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>                       
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint</compilerArgument>                 
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <includes>
                      <!-- Resources will be copied by the assembly
                      No need for it to be inside the jar 
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                        <include>**/types/*.xml</include>                       
                        <include>**/META-INF/**</include>
                        -->
                      </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                       <configuration>
                          <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                          <goals>deploy</goals>
                          <arguments>-Papache-release -DskipTests</arguments>
                          <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId> 
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                </plugin>               
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven expects tests to start or end with "Test", not "Tests", so 
                    explicitly include files ending in "Tests" -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                            <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <argLine>-Xmx3g</argLine>
                        <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>900</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
                        <additionalClasspathElements>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-assertion-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>                            
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-assertion-zoner-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-chunker-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                     <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-clinical-pipeline-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                     <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-constituency-parser-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-core-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-coreference-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-dependency-parser-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>    
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-drug-ner-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>                                                                                                                                                                                             
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-lvg-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-ne-contexts-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-pos-tagger-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>                           
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-relation-extractor-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-side-effect-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-smoking-status-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-temporal-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                            <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-ytex-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                     <additionalClasspathElement>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast-res/src/main/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                        </additionalClasspathElements>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8</version>      
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase> 
                            <goals> 
                                <goal>check</goal> 
                            </goals>                        
                            <id>default-cli</id>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration> 
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- File generated by maven-release-plugin -->
                                <exclude>release.properties</exclude>
                                <!-- Eclipse launch files -->
                                <exclude>**/*.launch</exclude>
                                <!-- Exclude target and eclipse files
                                The default RAT ignoreEclipse doesn't work
                                if there is a submodule that is commented out
                                So excluding it explictly here -->
                                <exclude>**/.classpath</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/.project</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/.settings/**</exclude>                                                                                                  
                                <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                <!-- Exclude bin/model resources -->
                                <exclude>**/resources/models/**</exclude>                               
                                <exclude>**/src/main/resources/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/src/test/resources/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/META-INF/org.uimafit/types.txt</exclude>                                
                                <!-- Exclude test data files -->
                                <exclude>**/data/test/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/data/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/output/**</exclude> 
                                <exclude>**/sample_note.txt</exclude>                                                                                           
                            </excludes>
                        <numUnapprovedLicenses>0</numUnapprovedLicenses>                                
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                <!-- 
                                This is needed to execute/unpack resources in m2e eclipse ide
                                Currently used in the ctakes-dictionary-lookup project  
                                -->
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>2.8</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                <!--
                                Ignore the Maven remote resources plugin in Eclipse. We don't use it from Eclipse,
                                and it causes a warning if m2e is not configured to ignore it as below.
                                -->                             
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>process</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>                                                              
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>disable-java8-doclint</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you load spring in your project ? maven/gradle/other?

Comment: share your POM.xml

Comment: @HarshMishra Shared

Comment: The accepted answer of the question you linked to explicitly specifies the `<dependency>` you need to add. If you don't know how to add that to your `pom.xml` file, then I strongly suggest you search the web so you can **learn** how Maven works.

Comment: @Andreas I already added that spring-jdbc ( it is in the pom.xml in the question above) but that does not fix the error

Comment: You have two conflicting `spring-jdbc` dependencies in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the `pom.xml` file. That doesn't mean your project uses it. To be used by your project, the `<dependency>` must be outside any `<dependencyManagement>` tag. As I said, find a guide and learn how Maven works, e.g. read the Maven documentation: [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You required the RowMapper for your use. So, It persists inside the "Spring-jdbc" Jar.

You have to import this jar into your pom.xml. When IDE automatically downloaded the jar, it will be visible in your code.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

RowMapper Github path:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.java

Other Versions:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.2.1.RELEASE

[Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) allows to consolidate and centralize the management of dependency versions without adding dependencies which are inherited by all children.

Comment: can you see the jar and RowMapper class in Lib/target?

Comment: And Error comes in java file? pls share that import line also

Comment: shared screenshot of it

Comment: @asmgx You never added a dependency to the `spring-jdbc` jar file, so it's not in the classpath. You added it to the `<dependencyManagement>` section, which serves a different purpose.

Comment: @Andreas I did, see POM.xml and I added screenshot

Comment: try to use <dependencies></dependencies> instead of dependencyManagement

Comment: this code dependencyManagement  is from the open source

Comment: @asmgx I see two `spring-jdbc` **INSIDE** the `<dependencyManagement>` element. I've told you that twice already, so hopefully a third time will make you hear me. When it's inside the `<dependencyManagement>`, it is *not* a project dependency. It has to be **OUTSIDE** for that to happen. **Read the Maven Guide** to learn what [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) is all about.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry I dont have the experience that you have, I am following other dependecies , they all INSIDE <dependencies> tag which is inside <dependencyManagement> tag.   if i am going to add that script provided by Harsh, where exactly shall i put it, within which tags?

Comment: @asmgx **Learn Maven**, then you'll know how. Regular dependencies is one of the very first things you'll learn in any Maven beginners guide, since that is one of the main purposes of Maven. StackOverflow is not a teaching site. If you use Maven, then you should take an hour or two to at least learn the basics.

Comment: Thanks the link you sent helped, it compiles now. I got another error but this one fixed