# HelloWorld Spring application throws Exception in thread "main": java.lang.NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to develop a Spring "HelloWorld" project while I am runing that application it gives me this error:

> INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser

Below is my code:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("your message : "+message);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld ");
    obj.getMessage();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint/HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Related question on Spring dependencies: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237537/which-maven-dependencies-to-include-for-spring-3-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237537/which-maven-dependencies-to-include-for-spring-3-0). Be sure to check your list of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

include

> spring-expression-3.1.1.Release.jar

under `lib` folder

I mentioned 3.1.1 as example you can use latest version, if any exist.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding all the dependent jars it seems like the `class` defined within the `bean` definition is *invalid*

```
com.tutorialspoint/HelloWorld
                  ^
```

make it,

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld"> 
     <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>
```

also `context.getBean("helloWorld ")`  should be changed to `context.getBean("helloWorld")`

Answer (score 0):

Add the spring dependencies to you class-path

Answer (score 0):

If you´re not using Maven, as M Sach says, add the "spring expression-X.Release.jar" to your "lib" folder and also DON´T forget to add it to the build path in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This Exception related to spring-expression.jar add this.

add below dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```