# Is it possible to download - all Spring jars in one bundle

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have question concerning to `spring framework` jars. Is it possible to download whole bundle in "one shoot" - e.g. relase - 4.0.0  - if yes how and where, or  shall i download `.jar` after `.jar` from  http://mvnrepository.com/  ?

Thank you indeed

Comment: Are we talking about a maven project?

Comment: Hi Raul, i forgot to mention it yes maven

Comment: I am used with doing it [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2237805/1300817). However, on the [documentation page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) the following is mentioned in order to start: `<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`. I tried it and it resolved `spring-core`, `spring-aop`, `spring-context`, `spring-expression` and `spring-beans`

Comment: And lets say - I have Spring project in Eclipse and i need to put springframework jars into classpath - shall i use the same approach? or is there another way?

Comment: Well, if you are not using Maven, you have to manually add them to your library. If you are using Maven, you just need to specify the dependencies in the pom.xml file and Maven takes care download them for you and place them so that they can be used in the project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are not using *Maven*, you need to do download the JARs manually one by one, or you can opt to download a ZIP [from here](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/), as there is no official link.

If you are using *Maven*, you can opt to include whichever *Spring* dependencies you need - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237805/1300817). This is also the way I prefer to do it.

On the [Spring documentation page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), they are suggesting doing it in the following way:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It resolves `spring-core`, `spring-aop`, `spring-context`, `spring-expression` and `spring-beans`.