# debug "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcpetion" error in Spring

Tags: mysql, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to create my own eshop. I have problem on the creation of beans.

**My packages are the following:**

**Controller**

```
package com.emusicstore.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList")
    public String getProducts(Model model) {
        List<Product> products = productDao.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "productList";
    }
```

**ProductDao**

```
package com.emusicstore.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
public interface ProductDao 
{
    void addProduct(Product product);
    Product getProductById (String id);
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    void deleteProduct (String id);
}
```

**ProductDaoImpl**

```
package com.emusicstore.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;

@Component
@Transactional
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addProduct(Product product) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(product);
    session.flush();
}

public Product getProductById(String id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
    session.flush();

    return product;
}

public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
    List<Product> products = query.list();
    session.flush();

    return products;
}

public void deleteProduct(String id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(getProductById(id));
    session.flush();
}

}
```

**Product**

```
package com.emusicstore.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String productId;
private String productName;
private String productCategory;
private String productDescription;
private double productPrice;
private String productCondition;
private String productStatus;
private int unitInStock;
private String productManufacture;

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductCategory() {
    return productCategory;
}

public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
    this.productCategory = productCategory;
}

public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}

public double getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String getProductCondition() {
    return productCondition;
}

public void setProductCondition(String productCondition) {
    this.productCondition = productCondition;
}

public String getProductStatus() {
    return productStatus;
}

public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
    this.productStatus = productStatus;
}

public int getUnitInStock() {
    return unitInStock;
}

public void setUnitInStock(int unitInStock) {
    this.unitInStock = unitInStock;
}

public String getProductManufacture() {
    return productManufacture;
}

public void setProductManufacture(String productManufacture) {
    this.productManufacture = productManufacture;
}

}
```

Also I have a jdbc.properties file with info about username, password etc to connect wit MySQL.
I think that the above files are correct.

**applicationContext.xml (part of my code)**

```
<beans profile="dev">
        <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.emusicstore.*</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
        </bean>
        <!-- Is <tx:annotation-driven /> is necessary in this file?? -->
</beans>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml (part of my code)**

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<context:annotation-config /> 
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**web.xml (part of my code)**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I try to run my project all the errors associated with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanCreationDefinitionException
```

The first error is on the creation of bean 'homeController'. 
    *Could not autowire field: private com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao com.emusicstore.controller.HomeController.productDao;*

My questions.

### 1) applicationContext.xml

On the  which file (or files) I have to put? Is the existing path right or I have to modify it specifically (e.g com.emusicstore.dao)? At this list, I have to put the whole path for my dao, model ?

### 2) dispatcher-servlet.xml

Same question for the right path of context:component-scan. On the base-package may I specify the package only to my controller (com.emusicstore.controller)?

I searched to older posts but I do not solve my problem.

Thank you in advance, Mike

**EDIT**

Summary of (our) changes

**applicationContext.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

        <beans profile="dev">

            <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore.dao, com.emusicstore.impl"></context:component-scan> 


            <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />

            <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">

                <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
                <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
                <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
                <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
            </bean>

            <!-- MY CHANGES -->
            <!-- LocalSessionFactoryBean for hibernate4 -->

            <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <props>
                        <!-- CHANGE HERE FOR MySQL -->
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
                <!-- To know where is ProductDao -->
                <property name="packagesToScan">
                    <list>
                        <value>com.emusicstore.dao</value>
                        <value>com.emusicstore.impl</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>

            <bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
            </bean>
            <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        </beans>
    </beans>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore." />

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**Web.xml** Exactly the same code as you wrote

The same errors continues to exist but the "homepage" on Eclipse has changed to this

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And then the previous errors again...

**EDIT**

**web.xml (first lines)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
```

**pom.xml (all my file)**

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
    <artifactId>eMusicStore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- To work with Hibernate -->
        <!-- All Hibernate in single dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySql -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To connect with the jdbc.properties file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Could you edit for making clear the first code you put above? It's not readable. Please modify it and I'll answer you.

Comment: @akuma8 I have just modified. I didn't know if it allowed to post too much code.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionnaly we have 2 contexts in a Spring MVC application. The root context (here your `applicationContext.xml`) where we define all beans not dedicated to web stuff like DAO, Securtity, etc... And the DispatcherServlet context (`dispatcher-servlet.xml`) where we define all beans related to web operations like controllers.

So, put your DAO bean in `applicationContext.xml` like this : `<context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore.dao"/>` and your transaction manager `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`

For your 2nd question, you can just put the super package like this : `<context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore."/>`

**EDIT**

Here how your web.xml should look like :

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param> 
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I your configuration you mixed the 2 contexts.

Comment: I added the suggested code but still I have the same error. Can I put sysout to print to my console to see where is the problem? Or this is not help me to solve the problems?

Comment: I have another question if you can help me. Do you want to post my pom.xml and my web.xml to make sure that I does not forget any code at this files? I am sorry for the inconvenience but I think that I (we at all) am close to solve the problem with your help.

Comment: With this exception you can't. The problem is Spring doesn't discover your beans to add them in its beans container for autowiring. Could you add your contexts configuration within web.xml?

Comment: Please add your web.xml file, just to see how you configured your context listeners.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that you have several DAO packages (com.emusicstore.dao and com.emusicstore.impl) , so add them to be scanning : `<context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore.dao, com.emusicstore.impl"/>` every package where you have a spring bean you should add it to be scanning.

Comment: I have just added code from web.xml. Check if it helps

Comment: See the EDIT, I modify your web.xml. You didn't separate the 2 contexts.

Comment: see the EDIT. I gathered the changes to see a new error apart from the previous.

Comment: Are your files (dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml) well located in /WEB-INF/?  You don't have a subdirectory ?

Comment: Once again I edited the initial post with an image to see all the folders..

Comment: Hello @akuma8. I edited one more time my post to see the first lines on web.xml and all the pom.xml...

Comment: Your pom lacks many crucial dependencies like the spring-context dependency. Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2237805/6643803 it will help you to add all dependencies that you need. And uncomment the `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Comment: I have just modified my pom.xml and the same error (edited my post)... The given link was very useful. As you can see my dependencies are also for Hibernate, MySql, dbcp, jtsl and taglibs. Maybe I forget something else or these dependencies are enough at this point of my project?

Comment: As your application should run in a server (Tomcat I suppose) your packaging in maven should be a war `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Comment: I corrected tha package but nothing newer.. Tha same errors.. I don't know what else we can do.. Where are trying one day.. Do you have another idea? (Only "thank you" is not enough for you help)

Comment: What I can suggest you is to start a new project which will work then you will add your hibernate dependencies later. To do that add Spring Tool Suite to Eclipse and go to `File->New-> Spring Legacy Project -> Spring MVC Project` it will generate you a pre-configured project which works fine and you can run it. To add Spring Tool Suite go to `Help->Eclipse MarketPlace` and in `Find` section write `STS` then install the 2 first results. Let me know if you encounter some trouble.

Comment: I will try and I'll be back!